# More than two dependent selectizeInputs cause an infinite loop in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

In the simple example below, I cannot select state 3 after selecting states 1 and 2. It works okay with 2 states, but as soon as I go to three states it infinite loops through the ObserveEvents. If it were the triggers from updating, I'd expect it to infinitely loop after selecting just the first state, but it doesn't.

I came across the `freezeReactiveValue()` function but when I freeze the `reactiveValues` in an attempt to not run the `observeEvent`, the selectizes don't update to prevent the user from selecting the same state twice.

Any ideas?

```
STATES <- c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT",
            "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL",
            "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD",
            "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM",
            "NY","NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA",
            "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT",
            "VT", "VA", "VI", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY")
ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  selectizeInput("state1", label = "State", 
                 choices = STATES,
                 selected = NULL,
                 multiple = FALSE,
                 options = list(placeholder = "Select a State",
                                onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
  
  selectizeInput("state2", label = "State", 
                 choices = STATES,
                 selected = NULL,
                 multiple = FALSE,
                 options = list(placeholder = "Select a State",
                                onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
  
  selectizeInput("state3", label = "State", 
                 choices = STATES,
                 selected = NULL,
                 multiple = FALSE,
                 options = list(placeholder = "Select a State",
                                onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) ({
  observeEvent(input$state1, {
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session, "state2",
      choices = setdiff(STATES,
                        c(input$state1, input$state3)),
      selected = input$state2
    )
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session, "state3",
      choices = setdiff(STATES,
                        c(input$state1, input$state2)),
      selected = input$state3
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$state2, {
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session, "state1",
      choices = setdiff(STATES,
                        c(input$state2, input$state3)),
      selected = input$state1
    )
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session, "state3",
      choices = setdiff(STATES,
                        c(input$state1, input$state2)),
      selected = input$state3
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$state3, {
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session, "state1",
      choices = setdiff(STATES,
                        c(input$state2, input$state3)),
      selected = input$state1
    )
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session, "state2",
      choices = setdiff(STATES,
                        c(input$state1, input$state3)),
      selected = input$state3
    )
  })
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The infinite loop is starting just right after you select second site. Use print choices in observeEvent of first site.

Comment: I see the problem, but I couldn't figure out how to solve it. Instead of setting "" in the selectize, I made it an option and selected it when initializing. That works fine, so it appears to be an issue with the onInitialize part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, the `onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')` causes the infinite loop since it gets called every time when `updateSelectizeInput` runs.

As an alternative you could do the following: Since the value of the `selectizeInput` shall be set to `""` when starting the app, you can also set `choices = NULL` inside your `ui`. This will automatically set the initial value to `""`. In order for then making the elements of  `STATES` selectable, put them into an `reactiveVal` inside your server

```
states <- reactiveVal(STATES)
```

and set the `choices` parameter of the `updateSelectizeInput` such that it uses `states()`:

```
choices = setdiff(states(), c(input$state1, input$state3))
```

Notice that for the below MWE I also corrected a presumed typo in your last `updateSelectizeInput` (set `selected = input$state2` instead of `input$state3`).

[image]

```
STATES <- c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT",
            "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL",
            "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD",
            "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM",
            "NY","NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA",
            "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT",
            "VT", "VA", "VI", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY")

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
    selectizeInput(
        "state1",
        label = "State",
        choices = NULL,
        selected = NULL,
        multiple = FALSE,
        options = list(placeholder = "Select a State")
    ),
    
    selectizeInput(
        "state2",
        label = "State",
        choices = NULL,
        selected = NULL,
        multiple = FALSE,
        options = list(placeholder = "Select a State")
    ),
    
    selectizeInput(
        "state3",
        label = "State",
        choices = NULL,
        selected = NULL,
        multiple = FALSE,
        options = list(placeholder = "Select a State")
    )
))

server <- function(input, output, session)
    ({
        states <- reactiveVal(STATES)
        
        observeEvent(input$state1, {
            updateSelectizeInput(
                session,
                "state2",
                choices = setdiff(states(),
                                  c(input$state1, input$state3)),
                selected = input$state2
            )
            updateSelectizeInput(
                session,
                "state3",
                choices = setdiff(states(),
                                  c(input$state1, input$state2)),
                selected = input$state3
            )
        })
        
        observeEvent(input$state2, {
            updateSelectizeInput(
                session,
                "state1",
                choices = setdiff(states(),
                                  c(input$state2, input$state3)),
                selected = input$state1
            )
            updateSelectizeInput(
                session,
                "state3",
                choices = setdiff(states(),
                                  c(input$state1, input$state2)),
                selected = input$state3
            )
        })
        
        observeEvent(input$state3, {
            updateSelectizeInput(
                session,
                "state1",
                choices = setdiff(states(),
                                  c(input$state2, input$state3)),
                selected = input$state1
            )
            updateSelectizeInput(
                session,
                "state2",
                choices = setdiff(states(),
                                  c(input$state1, input$state3)),
                selected = input$state2
            )
        })
        
    })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```